# How to make imageView go out as collapsingtoolbar reach at certain height

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I made this layout to have scrolling toolbar, the effects would be nice if I can make imageview to fade out, which is placed between the collapsing toolbar and coordinate layout like yellow favorite button in left phone image, added xml in which image is moving with collapsing toolbar but only disappearing at the toolbar not complete

[image: this]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
           />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            />
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv_poster"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Only upper part of image disappeared

Comment: try use this `app:scrimVisibleHeightTrigger="your_height"`

Comment: And how to place image like attached image

Comment: I don't understand what you want exatly for me the code is displaing the image lake the attached image, can you explain better what you want?

Comment: I want to place imageView like yellow favorite button in picture attach in question I posted

Comment: So i will create na answer with the code that you need because the code is to big to place in one comment.

Answer (score 0):

So, Like we talk in comments for the main question you can use this:

```
app:scrimVisibleHeightTrigger="your_height"
```

For the second question the you ask you can do that:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/your_icon"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>
```

So final code be like that:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:scrimVisibleHeightTrigger="your_height">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/your_icon"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Little question, when I'm using app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed" in place of app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" in collapsing toolbar the pin scroll mode of toolbar gone and toolbar disappeared with collapsing toolbar but when app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" toolbar maintains its position and does not disppear with scrolling toolbar, why?

Comment: Because the scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed means scroll the collapsingToolbar fully include the toolbar and when user scrolls back the toolbar shows first and when user reach top the image scrolls to you can read this article to better understand the scrollFlags. https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout

Comment: with your code image view moves with collapsing toolbar but didn't disppear completely only the part which was coverd by collapsing toolbar

Comment: can you add an image to better understand?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: thanks, So one more question, In your coordinatorLayout you only have textviews "hello world!"? Im ask that because seems strange your collapsing toolbar only hides the upper of image. Add full xml code to see exatly what you have

Comment: How about apply behavior to imageview

Comment: added full xml to the question

Comment: So, I think that your problem is this imageview :

`<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv_poster"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    />`